# Make items draggable with jquery draggable UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page, which has a jQuery draggable function --

```
function Drag() {
    $(function () {
        $($("span")).draggable({
            containment: "document"

        });
    });
      $(function () {
        $($("li")).draggable({
            containment: "document"

        });
    });
      $(function () {
        $($("a")).draggable({
            containment: "document"

        });
    });
      $(function () {
        $($("div")).draggable({
            containment: "document"

        });
    });
}
```

But I don't want to add for each elements like that, it will take me much time, 
and will not be any good for me...

Any idea how I can loop throw the elements in the page and do draggable on each one of them.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, its `jQuery` not `jquery` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice would be to add a class like the following:

```js
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
   containment: "document 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's multiple selector

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. An alternative to this combinator is the .add()
>   method.

For example

```
$("span, li, a, div").draggable({
    containment: "document"
});
```

You might want to tweak the elements you are targetting, as this will apply on all elements you specified.

See http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ for reference.

Comment: If i do all "tr" or "td" then 2 items will be moved together, how can i stopped that from happing?

Comment: You could provide the `tr` and `td` you want to be draggable with a specific class.As you can see in the link I provided with my answer.